# Visual Studio 2020 how to stop filenames from being shortened in the tab

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio (2020 for me), the filename of open files are written in the tabs at the top of the screen.  If the filename is too long, it will be automatically shortened, i.e. instead of **ReallyLongFilename.cs** it will say **ReallyL...lename.cs**.

I want the entire filename to be displayed.  I realize that I can hover my mouse on the tab to see the entire path, and I realize that I can select the dropdown on the top right to see all open files.  That requires mouse and eye movement, when I just want eye movement.

Is there a setting for this?

[filenames_have_been_shortened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swbJE.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not really, but you can mitigate the problem by changing the tab minimum/maximum width via `Tools > Options > Environment > Tabs and Windows > Minimum Tab Width` and `Maximum Tab Width`. The default minimum is 60 and the default maximum is 215. Changing the `Maximum Tab Width` will allow you to see more of the filename.

Comment: Thank you sir!  I set the max to 999!  Seems to do the trick (unless I get a file with more than 999 characters, in which case I've got other problems).