# How to change tab size in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, code-formatting, visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-mac-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 for Mac (currently v17.4). I want to change tab size as they are too big. I cannot see such option anywhere and even in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-all-languages-tabs?view=vs-2019) it says it doesn't apply to Visual Studio for Mac. Is it possible that it isn't implemented in such a popular IDE or am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2020 how to stop filenames from being shortened in the tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73235530/visual-studio-2020-how-to-stop-filenames-from-being-shortened-in-the-tab)

Comment: @Casey what I mean is the amount of space I get after pressing `tab` button.

Answer (score 0):

`Tools > Options > Text Editor` and then choose `All Languages > Tabs` or `[Specific language] > Tabs`. From there you can choose how VS handles your tabs/spaces and auto-formatting of such.

Comment: Actually, I found it under `Source Code > Code Formatting > C# source code > Tab`. It's very hard to find, because, for some reason, you cannot scroll in this window. You have to manually make it bigger to see this option.